# Taking change - convergent iteration through iterate

Tags: haskell, community-challenge

For the Code Review [community challenge "Implement StackSTV"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5440/37660), the algorithm requires a "convergent iterative scheme" to calculate the keep ratios of candidates that have been elected.

To simplify the calculation of those keep ratios I have written following function to truncate an infinite list that calculates the keep ratio scheme's next step.

I wonder whether I missed some basic library function and whether the function is idiomatic haskell:

```
{-
    Take items from a list, as long as the last item taken is not the same as the next item in the list.
    Passing an empty list returns an empty list.
-}
takeModified :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
takeModified (x:xs) = [x] ++ go x xs
    where
    go :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
    go elem (x':xs')
       | elem == x' = []
       | otherwise  = [x'] ++ go x' xs'
    go elem [] = []
takeModified [] = []
```

Comment: Here's a oneliner: `map head . takeWhile (null . drop 1) . group`

Comment: @Gurkenglas not the same behaviour. `takeModified $ repeat 0` will lead to `[0]`, whereas your code leads to `[]`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I never include the first duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Typically, `where` clauses don't include full type annotations, though this is mostly a matter of personal preference.
- For prepending items to a list, prefer `x:xs` over `[x] ++ xs`.
- In your "base case" of the recursive `go` function: `go elem [] = []`, `elem` is not used. Prefer `_` in this case.
- Your comment exceeds 80 characters in width. Again, a matter of personal preference. The note about passing an empty list returns an empty list is *probably* not necessary as this is very clearly the case from the code itself.

Here is how I would write this function:

```
takeWhileNotDup :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
takeWhileNotDup [] = []
takeWhileNotDup (x:xs) = x:go x xs
  where
    go _ [] = []
    go previous (x:xs)
      | previous /= x = x:go x xs
      | otherwise = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Using type annotations in `where` or `let` clauses can be misleading. The `a` in `go`'s type is not the same as the one in `takeModified`. Here's an example that shows that both `a`s differ:

```
idPair :: (a, b) -> (a, b)
idPair (x,y) = (x, f y)
  where
    f :: a -> a
    f k = k
```

This compiles fine, even though we've used `a`, not `b`. So our `a`s arent' really the same. This behaviour can be changed with [`-XScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XScopedTypeVariables), but it's something to keep in mind. For example, if you had checked that none of the elements were the same as the first, you would have gotten a type error:

```
takeWhileNotfirst :: [a] -> [a]
takeWhileNotfirst [] = []
takeWhileNotfirst xs@(first:_) = first : go xs
  where
    go :: [a] -> [a]           -- uh oh
    go (x:xs)
      | x == first = []        -- first is a, but x is another a!
      | otherwise  = x : go xs
    go _ = []
```

We now get yelled on by GHC:

```
Example.hs:7:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `a1' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for takeWhileNotfirst :: [a] -> [a]
          at Test.hs:1:22
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for go :: [a1] -> [a1] at Test.hs:5:11
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: [a1] (bound at Test.hs:6:11)
      x :: a1 (bound at Test.hs:6:9)
      go :: [a1] -> [a1] (bound at Test.hs:6:5)
      first :: a (bound at Test.hs:3:23)
      xs :: [a] (bound at Test.hs:3:19)
      takeWhileNotfirst :: [a] -> [a] (bound at Test.hs:2:1)
    In the second argument of `(==)', namely `first'
    In the expression: x == first
```

In this case, `go`'s type would be too general. So keep that in mind.

Other than that, I would prefer to use the simple cases (without `where`) first, so that the function doesn't get fenced by itself. But that's personal preference. However, there is already a function called `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` in `Prelude`. You should try not to use names from `Prelude`, as it can lead to very interesting results if you change your code, e.g.

```
-- 1st version
go elem (x:xs)
  | elem == x = ...

-- some time later you refactor, but forget to change the second elem

-- 2nd version
go previous (x:xs)
  | elem == x = ...   -- get yelled at by ghc, since "elem" is a function
```

But that's a problem in every programming language and not exclusive to Haskell.

> I wonder whether I missed some basic library function and whether the function is idiomatic haskell:

Unfortunately there is no such library function, so that we can write it point-free for example. You can certainly build one with the same functionality, but it's clunky, and we need a helper:

```
takeWhileInclusive :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhileInclusive _ [] = []
takeWhileInclusive p (x:xs) = x : if p x then takeWhileInclusive p xs else []

takeModified :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
takeModified xs = map fst (takeWhileInclusive (uncurry (/=)) (zip xs (tail xs)))
```

Yeah, that's not really easier to read. However, we can get rid of your helper, if we simply pattern match on two list elements:

```
takeModified :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
takeModified (x:y:xs) = x : if x == y then [] else takeModified (y:xs)
takeModified xs       = xs
```

Since you seem to prefer guards, we can also write the other cases first instead. Why? Because I prefer to use guards or patterns with `where` clauses last (personal preference, really):

```
takeModified :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
takeModified []       = []
takeModified [x]      = [x]
takeModified (x:y:xs) = 
    | x == y    = [x]
    | otherwise = x : takeModified (y:xs)
```

Either way, your original code was mostly fine. But I would keep in mind that you can pattern match on multiple elements of a list.